# JQuery UI Dialog Issue with Multiple Dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have several dialogs (jquery-ui-ified), they all look something like this:

```
$('#options_dlg').dialog({
    modal:true,
    stack:true,
    autoOpen:false,
    resizable:false,
    title:'Options',
    height:620,
    width:520,
    zIndex:20000 
});
```

The issue I am experiencing is that when i have a dialog open, and then I open another dialog, or close another dialog, it re-positions the first dialog - sometimes moving it so I can no longer access the title-bar to move it around.

There are of course numerous things going on in the script that may be the culprit - although nothing that is obvious to me -- meaning, I have no code that specifies that by opening or closing a dialog, than it should relocate any other dialogs.

So my question is, has anyone experienced this before in any capacity, and/or does anyone have any insight as to what could cause this to happen -- anything at all I can use to begin tracking down the culprit would be helpful.

Thanks -

Comment: It appears this is related to jquery-ui 1.8.14. I swapped out to version 1.7.2, and the issue doesn't occur. So, I guess maybe I should submit this to jquery ui team?

Comment: Can you put together a quick demo?

Comment: what about 1.8.16? whenever i've experienced weird issues like that it is almost always because there are elements with duplicate ID's or something like that in that page.

Answer (score 2):

I did have similar issues in and only in **IE** with jquery-ui 1.8.16. It looks like a [known issue](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dialog-position-issue) and I used the following method

```
$dialog.parent().css({position:"fixed"}).end().dialog('open');
```

from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657076/jquery-ui-dialog-fixed-positioning) and solved it. You might have a try, too.

Comment: Almost 2 years later using the latest version of jquery ui and this fixed my problem exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the position of the dialog box when you open it.

```
$('#options_dlg').dialog({
    modal:true,
    stack:true,
    autoOpen:false,
    resizable:false,
    title:'Options',
    position: [x,y],
    height:620,
    width:520,
    zIndex:20000 
});
```

And before you set up the dialog, initialize x and y to be offsets depending on where you want the dialog to appear.

For example:

```
x = $(cell).offset().left + $(cell).outerWidth();
y = $(cell).offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
```

You'll have to figure out how to determine the x and y offsets for your application, but that should fix the dialog position so that it does not move randomly when other dialogs are used.