# jQuery ui dialog stick to bottom while scroll

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using a jquery ui dialog and I want it to popup in the bottom left cornet of the window and will "stick" there while scrolling.
I tried several options like:

> $("#dialogue").dialog({ position: { my: "left bottom", at: "left
>   bottom", of: window } });

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657076/jquery-ui-dialog-fixed-positioning)  but they won't work.
How can I show the popup in the bottom left corner and leave it there while scrolling?

Comment: Why not use `position:fixed`?

Comment: Tried this one. doesn't work. it fixes it to the bottom of the page no matter scrolling.

Comment: I am unsure as to what behavior you're looking for then

Comment: if I put position:fixed it fixes to the top of page and not in the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried `position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:0px;`?

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet:

```
#dialogue {
     position:fixed;
     bottom:0px; 
     left:0px;
}
```

Comment: bottom:0px; fixes it to the top of the page.

Comment: By definition, it doesn't. Sounds like you have something else going on. Show us your source.